# torch matmul two matrix row by row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I want to find a decent way to write the below function in `torch`. Appreciate for clean solution to complete this.

```
import torch
a=torch.randn(3,100)
b=torch.randn(3,100)
row_num = a.size()[0] # 3

# Given two matrix with shape (n1,n2)
# I want to have the row-wise `matmul` results which will result in a tensor with size (n1, ) 

scores = []
for i in range(row_num):
    score_i = a[i,:].matmul(b[i,:])
    scores.append(score_i)
expected_result = torch.tensor(scores)
```

Answer (score 1):

The operation you are trying to do is essentially the values of a dot product (`matmul, a @ b.T`) which lie on its diagonal.

You can get the same using `torch.matmul` or `@` operator between a and b.T and then get the `torch.diagonal` -

```
np.diagonal(a @ b.T)
```

You can also use `torch.einsum` directly to get the same result -

```
torch.einsum('ij,ij->i',a,b)
```

Comment: ..or `torch.mm`!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, another option is

```py
expected_result = (a * b).sum(dim=1)
```